# How to prevent soft keyboard from appearing on touch

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I don't want the soft keyboard to appear when a particular EditText is touched. But I still want to be able to show the soft keyboard upon user request (say, when a button is pressed) and allow the user to edit the text.
I know how to show/hide the soft keyboard, I only don't know how to prevent it from appearing on touch.
Any suggestion how to do it?

The general idea is that the user will be mostly working with selection/position within the text, and only occasionaly entering characters.
I don't want the visible amount of text to be reduced by the soft keyboard when selecting or navigating the text.

Comment: Use these in your XML    android:editable="false"
                    android:focusable="false" and after that you can show the Alert Dialog box so that the user can select options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply use

```
 txtEdit.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

and when you want to enable that , reverse above process

Comment: Thanks, setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false) works. I am not sure why all the reflection stuff...

Comment: @Rediska as you said reflection is not needed but in android studio when i tried to find this method it wasn't in suggestion list and just if your api is 21 or higher you can apply this method ,

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

within the activity in the manifest add the below code
     android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: This will affect every EditText in activity, not a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidManifest.xml [windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html)

```
 <activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, it hides the keyboard:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN)
```

Comment: First, it doesn't work, and second, I am designing a custom component, so it is not appropriate to change app-wide settings

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you disable the edittext. Then it will not show keyboard on click. To this you can:

```
android:editable="false" //from xml
et.setEnabled(false);  //from activity
```

And then on your buttonClick make it enable by setting above code true. And make your keyboard appear.

Also If you don't get the focus on edittext  you can:

```
et.requestFocus(); // from activity

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:editable="false"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <requestFocus/>
</EditText>
```

//from xml

Hope this helps!